# importing ant build.xml to eclipse says "javac" task not found in target "compile"

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, hadoop, javac

I have jdk 6 installed on Mac OSX Mountain Lion and I am able to create new java projects directly from eclipse.

I am trying to modify the code written by alex holmes at [json-mapreduce (https://github.com/alexholmes/json-mapreduce)](https://github.com/alexholmes/json-mapreduce). My first goal is to bring the code into eclipse build so I can debug the code. 
I did the following:

```
Launch Eclipse -> File -> New Project -> New project from ant build file 
-> select the build.xml downloaded from the above link
```

It throws the following errors:

```
<> "javac" task not found in target "compile"
<> "java" task not found in target "test"
```

Eclipse shows the code, but is not doing any builds or running any tests. It seems like something is going wrong due to above errors, however I can see other java projects created inside eclipse work fine.

(Eclipse shows the installed JRE location: `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home`)

Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Can you check the jre location for those programs.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I verified the JRE location and eclipse is using the same JRE location.

Comment: Does it run from the command line outside Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, it runs fine from command line, all tests pass and build succeeds. I need to upgrade to newer libraries and hence want to bring it into eclipse first, so I can debug if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ant build scripts are in my experience - unless explicitly handled at design time - too unstructured to warrant easy IDE integration afterwards.

We experimented with using ant4eclipse to let ant compile existing Eclipse projects (by reading the .project and .classpath files) and it doesn't scale well.

If you have the time and political support, you may want to switch to maven which *does* scale.  This may however take quite some time if your current build process does not conform to the "one project, one resulting jar file".

If you do not, I would suggest that you forget everything about having Eclipse deal with build.xml and manually maintain Eclipse projects mirroring the build.xml configuration, and simply run ant from the command line when you need to (debugging as a remote java application if needed).

Comment: I would like to follow the last step.. in order to mirror the build.xml configuration to Eclipse, what is the best way to go about it?

Comment: @Maverickgugu Don't! Switch to maven.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to set the java path in your targets as mentioned here:

```
<target name="compile">
  <javac target="1.5" srcdir=.../>
</target>
```

Comment: Do you mean another javac? Build file already has the following:         <javac debug="true" srcdir="src/main/java" destdir="build/classes">
            <classpath refid="lib.path.ref"/>
        </javac>
However, I did give it a try and doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Then make sure the project compiler settings are proper and check whether there is any jdk path mentioned in any of the targets in the ant

Comment: can you be more specific? I gave the link to the complete source which has build.xml and I am able to build other projects in eclipse.